# Error while inserting data into table by apex_data_parser

Tags: oracle-apex

I used the following code to enter information in my table, but I get an error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-20987: No data found in uploaded file.
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DATA_PARSER", line 5384
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DATA_PARSER", line 4782
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Does anyone know what the reason is and how to solve it?

The data is in the file upload and when I remove the where or joins, the operation is done!!
But I want only one specific line, for example line 2, to be entered into the database.
The interesting thing is that this code was working fine until 2 days ago, but now it gives me this error.

```
Insert into emp (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO)
            Select col001,col002,col003,col004,col005,col006,d.ID
                   from apex_application_temp_files f,
                   table ( apex_data_parser.parse (  
                   p_content=> f.blob_content,
                   p_file_name=> f.filename))
             left join dept d on d.code=col007
             Where LINE_NUMBER = 2;
```

Comment: Sounds pretty obvious: **No data found in uploaded file**

Comment: The data is in the file upload and when I remove the where or joins, the operation is done!!
But I want only one specific line, for example line 2, to be entered into the database.
The interesting thing is that this code was working fine until 2 days ago, but now it gives me this error.

Comment: Aha. So, something happened 2 days ago. If you didn't change anything, was it someone else? Try to create a **report** whose source is that SELECT statement, so that you'd see what Apex sees. Maybe you'll find the culprit, then.

Comment: @Littlefoot Nothing has changed in these two days. I also put a classic report that displays the data in the apex_application_temp_files table and there is no problem, but I don't know why it gives me this strange error!!

Comment: Just to confirm: COL007 actually contains data that can be joined to DEPT.CODE values? No *trailing spaces*, non-printable characters? Did you try to show DUMP(COL007) - it'll show which characters it really contains (their ASCII codes). Also, I presume that row whose LINE_NUMBER = 2 exists, right?